# Here in line 81 there is an error that I need to remove by making changes in the class

Tags: c++

The error is in line 81 under "str4.length()" that I need to remove. I cannot change a single word of main but I can alter the Class. I am not sure why this is occurring. The function length is supposed to be outside the class as it can be seen how it is being called. But not working with this "const MyString str4;"

Please ignore any other Errors after line 81.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyString
{
    char var[100];
public:
    MyString()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            this->var[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    MyString(MyString str1, int start, int end)
    {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            var[index++] = str1.var[i];
        }
    }
    char* get_var()  
    { 
        return var;
    }
    void add(char var) 
    {
        static int index = 0;
        this->var[index++] = var;
    }
    
     int length()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; var[i] != '\0'; i++)
            count++;
        return count;
    }
    
};
void print(MyString var)
{
    
    for (int i = 0;var.get_var[i]()!= '\0'; i++)
        cout << var.get_var[i]() << " ";
    cout << endl;
    
}
int main()
{
    MyString str1;// make a default string of 100 size
    str1.add('[');//insert at position 1 or index 0
    str1.add('A');//insert at position 2 or index 1
    str1.add('B');//insert at position 3 or index 2
    str1.add('C');//insert at position 4 or index 3
    str1.add('D');//insert at position 5 or index 4
    str1.add('E');//insert at position 6 or index 5
    str1.add('F');//insert at position 7 or index 6
    str1.add('G');//insert at position 8 or index 7
    str1.add('h');//insert at position 9 or index 8
    str1.add('i');//insert at position 10 or index 9
    str1.add('j');//insert at position 11 or index 10
    str1.add('k');//insert at position 12 or index 11
    str1.add('l');//insert at position 13 or index 12
    str1.add('m');//insert at position 14 or index 13
    str1.add('n');//insert at position 15 or index 14
    str1.add('o');//insert at position 16 or index 15
    str1.add('p');//insert at position 17 or index 16
    str1.add(']');//insert at position 18 or index 17
    cout << "str1\n";
    print(str1);
    cout << "Lenghth of str1 is = " << str1.length() << endl;
    cout << "str2\n";
    MyString str2(str1, 2, 9);//should copy str1 to str2 from position 2 to 9
    print(str2);
    cout << "Lenghth of str2 is = " << str2.length() << endl;
    cout << "str4\n";
    const MyString str4; //It should accesss all constant functions
    print(str4);
    cout << "Lenghth of str4 is =" << str4.length() << endl;
    str1.clear();//It should clear the string by placing null char at all indexes and setting count to zero
        cout << "After clearing str1\n";
    print(str1);
    str1.add('$');
    cout << "After adding $ to str1\n";
    print(str1);
    MyString str3;
    str3 = str1 + str2;//It will concatenate both the strings and assign it to str3
    cout << "str3\n";
    print(str3);
    MyString str5(5);//should make an empty array of size 5
    str5.add('a');
    str5.add('B');
    str5.add('c');
    str5.add('D');
    str5.add('e');
    cout << "str5\n";
    print(str5);
    str5[0] = str5[1] + 1; //add 1 to the char at 1st index and assign it to 0th index
    print(str5);
    print(str5++);//post-increment
    print(++str5);//pre-increment
    print(--str5);//pre-decrement
    print(str5--);//post-decrement
    MyString str8;
    str8 = str5;//assigning str5 to str8
    cout << "str8\n";
    print(str8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the error? Please incldue the compilers error message in the quesiton.

Comment: well the error is complaining about you trying to call a non-const method on a `const` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call a non-const method on a `const` instance. Thats the whole point of declaring an isntance as `const`. A non-const method is allowed to modify (observable) state of the instance, but a `const` instance is constant.

By default you should declare methods that need not modify members of `this` as `const`:

```
class MyString
{
    char var[100];
public:
   // ...  
   int length() const              // <------------
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; var[i] != '\0'; i++)
            count++;
        return count;
    }
    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The goal of this exercise is to practice with `const` member functions. `MyString::length` is not yet a `const` member function. It can be, since getting the length of a string does not alter the string. So you should fix that.